# Image in chat bubble having unwanted margins

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image

I am having this simple layout for chat bubble.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/bubble_layout_chat_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bubble_layout_chat"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/message_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#999"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

However, when I set image it leaves unwanted margins above and below the image.

[image]

How can I remove margins and make the bubble to fit image?

(Note: What I observed is the margins appears only when image width is larger than height. For images having width much smaller than height no margins observed)

Comment: Just off the top of my head, have you tried:
- setting margins to 0?
- examining the layout in Android Device Monitor (or using background colors) so you can tell exactly what portion of the space is from the ImageView and what from its container?

Comment: Check if the image itself have margins on top and bottom

Comment: @kgandroid: No. Image doesn't have margins for sure.

Comment: try setting android:layout_height="150dp" of the parent linear layout and just check the output...then you may find what the problem is

Comment: Tried setting margins without any luck. Effect is same.

Comment: Play around with the ImageView's scaleType property. Also your height and width of ImageView are wrap_content, you need to set a proper height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's comments. Setting `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to `ImageView` fixed my problem. So my working `ImageView` now looks like:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/message_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` for your imageview

Comment: This stretched image vertically. But thanks for hints. Finally `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` worked for me.